# Button in the JQ list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a list of favorites is filled by code as follows:

```
function FillBook() {
    var select = $("#bookMarkMenu");
    var ul = document.getElementById("bookMarkMenu");
    for (var i = 0; i < Local.length; i++) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
        ul.appendChild(newLI);
            newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="to.html" data-transition="slide" dir="rtl">    
<p>...</p> </a>';
        newLI.setAttribute('data-theme', 'c');
        newLI.setAttribute('onclick', 'DisplayBookMark()');
    }
    $('ul').listview('refresh');
}
```

I want to add a button for each instance on a list,

I tried to add the next one:

```
 <a id="btnClearOneBookmark" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="xxx();"></a>
```

like this:

```
newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="to.html" data-transition="slide" dir="rtl">    
<p>...</p><a id="btnClearOneBookmark" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="xxx();"></a> </a>';
```

is not added ..why?

Comment: how??where?? did u add the button ?? i cannot see it in your code?? post your other(Added part) codes too...

Comment: What do you mean under 'Local' variable in your sample? Does it exist? I cannot find it in the sample as the result this code will always fail.

Comment: This array, the code does not fall he ran but in html not see the button and is also not recognized in F12 of Chorme

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nR369/1/

Comment: Exactly, but on my project the button is not displayed at all

Comment: I have used the same code that you have posted .. I suspect that you might have left out the data-role = "listview" attribute from the unordered list with id "bookMarkMenu".please let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: this is my ul:    <ul id="bookMarkMenu" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        </ul>

Comment: There is nothing wrong in it you can take a look at it here http://jsfiddle.net/nR369/2/ my bad.Any errors in the debugger log?

Comment: Not in Chrome's Debugger is not know the button, it shows like the button is not there at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<a data-role = "button" id = "mybutton">Click me</a>
<ul id="bookMarkMenu" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true"> </ul>

<div id='buttons' style='visibility:hidden'>
    <a href="to.html" data-transition="slide" dir="rtl">    
    <p>...</p>
    <a id="btnClearOneBookmark" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="xxx();"></a>      
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#bookMarkMenu").append("<li data-theme='c' onClick='DisplayBookMark();'>"+$('#buttons').html()+"</li>");
}
$("#bookMarkMenu").listview('refresh'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i could see one extra `'` in your code... try using this...

```
newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="to.html" data-transition="slide" dir="rtl"><p>...</p>' +'<a id="btnClearOneBookmark" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="xxx();"></a>'+' </a>';
```

Comment: It's just in the question on my code there is no extra ', that is also running.. only he did not recognize the button.